# How to batch export Unity3d prefab files to FBX format?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, fbx

I have Unity3d project where in the assests folder I have 1000 prefab files. I want to convert them to fbix format or meshobj format. Is there any program that can bulk convert prefab to fbix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I found is a bit lengthy. I needed to convert prefab files to fbx format and then used blender to convert fbx files into wavefrontObj.
To convert prefab files to fbx file format I used a Unity Package called [FBX Exporter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.formats.fbx@2.0/manual/index.html). The installation guide that I followed is from [here](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/working-with-the-fbx-exporter-setup-and-roundtrip-2019#).

After converting the files into fbx format I used blender to convert the files into obj format. I only needed the mesh files, so I excluded materials.To batch convert fbx files to wavefrontObj files I wrote the following script.

```
import bpy
import glob

fbx_file_folder = "input_folder/*.fbx"

mylist = [f for f in glob.glob(fbx_file_folder)]

for input_file in mylist:
    output_file = input_file.split(".")[0]
    output_file  = output_file + ".obj"
    print(output_file)
    bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings(use_empty=True)
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=input_file)
    bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(filepath=output_file,use_materials=False,check_existing=True)
```

To run the script, save the files as `convertFBXtoOBJ.py` and in terminal run the following command once blender is installed.

```
blender --python convertFBXtoOBJ.py
```

To get information about the API that I have used for the script, [Blender PyDocs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_quickstart.html) will be a great help.